# Grab the end of a URL after the last slash with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to be able to grab the number at the end of the url, and set it as the value of a textbox. I have the following, but it's not correctly stripping out the beginning of the URL before the last slash. Instead, its doing the opposite.

```
<input id="imageid"></input>

var referrerURL = "http://subdomain.xx-xxxx-x.xxx.url.com/content/assets/750";
var assetID = referrerURL.match("^(.*[\\\/])");
$("#imageid").val(assetID);
```

The result of the regex match should set the value of the text box to `750` in this case.

JSFiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/ptbmoq2n/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple method is to use a negated character class as

```
/[^\/]*$/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uY4hV2/2)

**Example**

```
var referrerURL = "http://subdomain.xx-xxxx-x.xxx.url.com/content/assets/750";
alert(referrerURL.match(/[^\/]*$/));
// Output
// => 750
```

Comment: Will do, just waiting for the timer to end (can't accept an answer so quickly after its been posted apparently)

Answer (score 1):

Can use a simple split() and then pop() the resultant array

```
var assetID = referrerURL.split('/').pop();
```

Easier to read than a regex thus very clear what it is doing

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ptbmoq2n/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```js
var referrerURL = "http://subdomain.xx-xxxx-x.xxx.url.com/content/assets/750";
var myregexp = /.*\/(.*?)$/;
var match = myregexp.exec(referrerURL);
$("#imageid").val(match[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="imageid"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try avoiding the usage of regular expression for this task just by using native javascript's string functions.

- Splitting the text:

  ```
  var lastSlashToken = referrerURL.split("/").pop(-1);
  ```
- Looking up for the last ending "/text" token:

  ```
  var lastSlashToken = referrerURL.substr(referrerURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  ```

However, if you still want to use regular expression for this task, you could try using the following pattern:

```
.*\/([^$]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Working DEMO example @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nB8gC6/1)